# Flet integration (modularization) with other Flutter/Dart code

Tags: interop, flet

I love the idea of combining the power (and existing libraries) of python with the rich user interfaces of Flutter, however I wonder about how Flet can interact with existing Flutter code-bases.

Specifically, is it possible to incorporate Flet into existing Flutter apps? Can I write a specific business-logic module in Flet (via python) and then access that module via standard Dart/Flutter?

I think such a mechanism would provide a lot of utility for developers, allow for a larger range of (language) expressivity in Flutter apps and make it easier for established codebases to adapt Flet without having to start from scratch.

FYI: I know that Flutter packages for python integration exist (e.g. [Chaquopy](https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy) and [Starflut](https://pub.dev/packages/starflut/example), or just running a custom python-based on-device web-service), but I am intrigued by the more native integration that Flet could afford (less marshalling logic, etc.)